# What are the necessary steps to completely wipe & reinstall Windows 7 Home Premium on my Acer 5742?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, reinstall, acer-aspire

I have an Acer 5742 with Windows 7 Home Premium (bloatware included)

What are the necessary steps for me to take to completely wipe the hard drive and reinstall Windows 7 Home Premium to prep for sale?

I do not own the Windows 7 installation disk since it was already installed when I purchased the laptop.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, or what *specific* problem are you having? Your question as it stands is a bit broad and unclear.

Comment: Unclear? "to prep for sale" They want to sell it without passing along personal files or the possibility of recovering them by the new owner.

Answer (score 0):

You may

- Reinstall Windows7 from OEM Recovery Options.
- Delete personal files from Other partitions.
- Wipe the free space.
- And sell.

To Wipe the Free Space, use the program [Eraser](http://eraser.heidi.ie/). During Wiping 1 overwrite is enough. The recent versions of Eraser might require [Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (Standalone Installer)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=17718)

Comment: Not sure why you got a downvote, your answer is correct as I have used this method for years.

Comment: That would just start flame wars, probably why they make them anonymous also. I upvoted.